# Redux Sagas, TypeScript, and call?

Tags: typescript, redux-saga

As a TypeScript and redux-thunk user, I am curious about the benefits offered by redux-saga. I'd like to give it a shot but am concerned about the `call` function and the apparent loss of type safety.

If I do this:

```
function* invalidateReddit(): SagaIterator {
  while (true) {
    const {reddit} = yield take(actions.INVALIDATE_REDDIT)
    yield call( fetchPosts, reddit )
  }
```

The compiler will not be able to check calls to `fetchPosts`. So if I changed the signature to not include the argument...

```
function fetchPosts() {
  // anything here...
}
```

The `invalidateReddit` function, which depends on `fetchPosts`, *should* fail to compile but it will not because `call` evaluates my code for me. Is there an established pattern for using this without sacrificing type safety?

UPDATE: The PR at https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/pull/740 looks like it attempts to solve this problem. I will leave this open until it can be closed with a solution.

Comment: Seems like PR mentioned in UPDATE is not working. I've tried latest code on branch and it's `any` type. It's probably issue with TypeScript itself, but doesn't look like they are working on enabling custom types on `yield` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Because TypeScript won't complain about excess variables you passed to a function.

As the type declaration per se, 
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/redux-saga/index.d.ts#L75

```
export function call<T1, T2, T3>(fn: EffectFunction<T1, T2, T3>, arg1?: T1, arg2?: T2, arg3?: T3, ...rest: any[]): Effect;
```

If you pass a function with arity less than 3 to `call`, all the type parameter will be inferred to `{}`, the top type of TS. So basically every thing will be assignable in such call `call(zeroArityFunc, anything)`.

At runtime, excess argument won't cause error, so your code should be fine.
If `fetchPosts` does require argument, then the type parameter for it will be inferred and a compiler error will be raised.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I cannot trigger a compiler error for any code that uses `call` at the moment, regardless of arity. I just noticed an open PR, https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/pull/740, that might be intended to solve the problem I am describing.